# How to set sqlt_datatype at SQL::Abstract/DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, dbix-class, sql-abstract

I can not write this condition: `app_period => { '@>' => '2021-03-15' }` because I get an error:

```
malformed range literal: "2021-03-15"
```

Here how my query looks:

```
->search( $cond, @_ )->as_query
  \[
      (SELECT "me"."id", "me"."order_id", "me"."resource_type_id", "me"."service_type_id", "me"."amount", "me"."allocated_resource_id", "me"."last_used", "me"."app_period", "me"."sort_order" FROM "order_detail" "me" WHERE ( ( "app_period" @> ? AND "order_id" = ? ) )),
      [
        {
          dbic_colname => app_period,
          sqlt_datatype => tstzrange,
        },
        2021-03-15,
      ],
      [
        {
          dbic_colname => order_id,
          sqlt_datatype => integer,
        },
        11961,
      ],
    ]
```

I have found [this documentaion](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#DBIC-BIND-VALUES) and tried:

```
{ app_period => { '@>' => [ \'timestamptz' => '2021-03-15' ] } }
```

But got error: `column "timestamptz" does not exist`

How to set correct `sqlt_datatype` for bind value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I found how to accomplish this. I should pass this hash to `->search(...)`:

```
{ app_period => \[ '@> ?::timestamptz', [ { sqlt_datatype => 'timestamptz ' },  '2021-03-15' ] ] }
{ app_period => \[ '@> ?::timestamptz', [ \'timestamptz'                     => '2021-03-15' ] ] }
```

And then I will get desired result:

```
\[
    (SELECT "me"."id", "me"."order_id", "me"."resource_type_id", "me"."service_type_id", "me"."amount", "me"."allocated_resource_id", "me"."last_used", "me"."app_period", "me"."sort_order" FROM "order_detail" "me" WHERE ( ( "app_period" @> ?::timestamptz ) )),
    [
      {
        sqlt_datatype => timestamptz,
      },
      2021-03-15,
    ],
  ]
```

I should instead of value pass `ARRAYREF`:
[doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#DBIC-BIND-VALUES)

```perl
[ $name => $val ] === [ { dbic_colname  => $name }, $val ]
[ \$dt  => $val ] === [ { sqlt_datatype => $dt   }, $val ]
[ undef,   $val ] === [ {}, $val ]
$val              === [ {}, $val ]
```

Where `[ {}, $val ]` was notices at this [section](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Abstract#Literal-SQL-with-placeholders-and-bind-values-(subqueries))

[image]

Still I did not changes `bindtype`, probably `DBIx::Class` did that.